# Security Hub findings - Identify the Resource Id

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-security-hub

In Security Hub -> Findings , I am trying to Identify a ResourceId but ResourceId contains Account Name and Account Id.
Where I can find a resource Id which is not linked to Account Id.
Let's say if I need to remediate it for a particular Resource, how I can do it ?

```
 "Resources": [
                {
                    "Type": "AwsAccount",
                    "Id": "AWS::::Account:220307202362",                        
                }
            ],
```

Comment: This is something specific for the account itself. Normally, if it's a specific resource (like EC2 instance), Type would be different, and you would have arn (ID) of the instance...

Comment: Can you give me a example of how typical Resource Id looks like ?

Comment: @Bokambo refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/securityhub/latest/userguide/securityhub-findings-format-attributes.html#asff-resources
The information under Resources will be based on the type of resource the finding is for like it has been pointed out in previous comment. The link will give you the attributes you can expect for each type of resource.